# After update/replace bootstrap-sass (3.3.7) to bootstrap (4.1.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I use RAILS 5.1 and I want to replace bootstrap-sass (3.3.7) by bootstrap (4.1.1). 
I followed the instructions on https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem and after that I see that the Load path still looks for bootstrap 3.3.7 files :

**File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap. 
    Load paths:**

```
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets 
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0./gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/javascripts
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/fonts 
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/images 
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets
```

How I can change the Load Path ?

Answer (score -1):

The solution as just to restart the rails server.